# Static link libpng into a shared library

Tags: c, shared-libraries, static-libraries, ld, static-linking

I've reduced the problem to this minimal test.c:

```
#include "png.h"

int function() {
    printf("%ld", (long)png_create_read_struct);
}
```

Compiling with

```
gcc -shared -fPIC test.c -o test.so -lm -l:libpng16.a
```

gives the error

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.a(pngread.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `png_sRGB_table' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
```

Now every answer I've found to this error boils down to "do what it says and recompile with -fPIC", but as you can see I'm already doing that. So what gives?

(Output above is from Ubuntu 17.10 with libpng16. Ubuntu 16.04 with libpng12 results in similar error.)

Comment: No, you're not already doing that.  The linker wants the objects in `libpng16.a` to be PIC, and they're not.  *That's* what it wants you to recompile with `-fPIC`.

Comment: Why not just link the libpng shared library?

Comment: @JohnBollinger So the static libraries shipped in the apt packages are not prepared for this, and I'd have to recompile everything I want to link statically? Damn. Is there any way to check if an .a file was compiled with -fPIC? (PS please make your comment an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now every answer I've found to this error boils down to "do what it says and recompile with -fPIC", but as you can see I'm already doing that. So what gives?

As I commented, no, in fact you're *not* already doing that. The linker wants the objects linked in from `libpng16.a` to be PIC, and they're not. *That's* what it wants you to recompile with `-fPIC`.

Although it is possible to store PIC objects in a regular archive such as `libpng16.a`, that is unconventional.  It is not without reason that these files are often called "static libraries".  They are ordinarily intended to support building static binaries, not shared ones, and that purpose is not served by PIC objects.  You should not expect any such archives provided by standard packages to contain PIC objects.

In any event, since you are building a shared library, the natural and appropriate thing to do would be to link to the shared version of libpng.  You've gone to some trouble to try to link the static library instead, but it is not clear why.  Whatever you're trying to accomplish, this is the wrong way to go about it, if even it's something worth accomplishing at all.

Comment: To your last question, I need to package python extensions that use old versions of libpng that are no longer packaged in current linux distros. I don't see why static linking would be the wrong way to go about it. Other options exist, but any solution that complicates deployment is an inconvenience. Of course having to compile libpng from source is also inconvenient, I'll have to figure out what is the "lesser evil" solution.

Comment: (oh, in case it's not obvious, a python extension has to be a dynamic library, so going all static is not an option)

Comment: @PedroLopes, linking to the static library is the wrong way to go about it quite simply because it doesn't work.  The right approach is to link to the appropriate shared libraries.  Different versions of the same shared library can coexist on the system, and some distributions even provide packages for that, for some specific libraries.

Answer (score 3):

#### Compiling libpng with -fPIC

```sh
user@user_pc:~/Documents$ mkdir libpng
user@user_pc:~/Documents$ cd libpng
user@user_pc:~/Documents/libpng$ wget https://download.sourceforge.net/libpng/libpng-1.6.37.tar.gz
user@user_pc:~/Documents/libpng$ tar xvfz libpng-1.6.37.tar.gz
user@user_pc:~/Documents/libpng$ cd libpng-1.6.37
user@user_pc:~/Documents/libpng/libpng-1.6.37$./configure --prefix=/home/user/Documents/libpng --with-pic=yes
user@user_pc:~/Documents/libpng/libpng-1.6.37$ sudo make
```

Your binaries are in `~/Documents/libpng/libpng-1.6.37/lib`, most interesting one is `libpng.a` which was now compiled with -fPIC.

It also solves problem when compiling blender on Linux as a Python module:

```
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.a(pngerror.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'stderr' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Hi Christopher, I have this exact issue with Blender on Ubuntu, trying to compile as a Python module. I've compiled libpng as you described, but how to now fix the blender error?

Comment: I need more explicit explanation of what blender error you have in mind? Im a missing context a bit, but if you are talking about libpng  missing fPiC error, you have to recompile blender (as Python module) but first you have to make sure it will use your freshly compiled fPiC libpng, by removing libpng which is already present in your pc and replacing it with your new build. It worked for me, but i have to admit, that i haven't reversed libpng swap, so I still have - fPiC variant as default on my system.

Comment: Thanks, Christopher. I was referring to the exact issue you highlighted in your post. I will try just replacing the libpng file, as you suggest.

Comment: Just to say thanks again -- replacing libpng.a worked.