# libpng.a(pngerror.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'stderr'

Tags: ubuntu, blender, libpng, fpic

I'm on Ubuntu 20 focal and I am trying to build [Blender as a Python module](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule).
The final step of the [build instructions](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu) is where I am having problems.

My building gets to 100%, but then fails with the following output:

```
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.a(pngerror.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'stderr' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
```

I have tried `sudo make bpy -fPIC`, but this throws another error:

```
make: pic: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'pic'. Stop.
```

I assume the `-fPIC` error is because I'm stupid, and I am supposed to compile libpng with fpic support (or something like that), rather than tack it on to the end of the above command, but I don't know really...

I've searched for a while now, and the closest answer I've come to is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69118170/596841), which says to download and compule `libpng` and then to do something with `libpng.a` (what exactly, I've no idea).

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

add CFLAGS in Makefile when compile, like below:

```
CFLAGS = -fPIC -m64 -pthread -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -g

...
$(cc) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I ./ -std=c++0x
```

Reference: https://www.collabora.com/about-us/blog/2014/10/01/dynamic-relocs,-runtime-overflows-and-fpic/

Comment: There is no Makefile in the blender directory, are you referring to GNUmakefile? If so, which lines need to be edited? What does the "..." in your code snippet mean?